# Separating out words from sentence without spaces

Tags: python, string, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I basically have two problems that are related.

First, I have this dataset below.

```
['Dividingpolynomials', 'Categoricaldataandprobabilities', 'Systemsoflinearequations', 'Scatterplotsandgraphs', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Categoricaldataandprobabilities', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Scatterplotsandgraphs', 'Scatterplotsandgraphs', 'Scatterplotsandgraphs', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Scatterplotsandgraphs', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Manipulatingpolynomials', 'Dividingpolynomials', 'Scatterplotsandgraphs']
```

I was wondering how I would be able to edit the array to format it better.
Desired outcome is like `["Dividing Polynomials", "Categorical Data and Probabilities", "Systems of Linear Equations", "Scatterplots and Graphs", "Manipulating Polynomials"]`.
This is in Python and the result should be an array too.

Second problem is much simpler:

For a different section, my code formats a different dataset and it works fine.
The only problem is that the `And` is uppercase and I can't seem to modify it to make the and lowercase.
The code is written, it just needs a minor adjustment.

```
temptopiclist = [re.sub(r"and([A-Z])", r"And\1", element) for element in temptopiclist]
topiclist = [re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", element).title() for element in temptopiclist]
          
print(topiclist, "<br>", "<br>")
```

Resulting dataset that needs to be fixed:

```
['Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Basic Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Advanced Algebra', 'Problem Solving And Data Analysis']
```

Comment: For your first question: putting words together is trivial, dividing them is very hard.

Comment: "I was wondering how I would be able to edit the array to format it better." What is the rule that tells you where to make the splits? Why does the data look like this in the first place? Better to make sure the spaces are there from the start.

Comment: "The only problem is that the And is uppercase and I can't seem to modify it to make the and lowercase." What is the rule that tells you that `And` should be lowercase? Should anything else be lowercase?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I want And to be lowercase. In my dataset only And needs to be lowercase

Comment: `text.replace(" And ", " and ")`

Comment: Isn't `re.sub(r"and([A-Z])", r"And\1", element)` taking lowercase `and`s and uppercasing them in the first place? Why do that if it's not what you want?

Answer (score 1):

For your second problem, you can just do a search and replace as furas mentioned:

```
text.replace(" And ", " and ")
```

As for your first problem, as Klaus rightly mentioned in the comments, `putting words together is trivial, dividing them is very hard.`

However, its fun to solve hard problems.

One way to solve this is using recursion and [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).
Note that you will need to have access to a dictionary of commonly used words in English.
If you know all the words present in your dataset, you can enter them in `words_dict` list.
Otherwise, you'll need to get a publicly available list of words in the English dictionary.

The trie code can be obtained from [here](https://gist.github.com/Anmol-Singh-Jaggi/9309ce6b1900a1b283fb9d130eb4a37c).

```
from collections import deque
from trie import Trie


def partition_valid_words(start_pos, end_pos, trie, input_phrase, cache):
    pos_pair = (start_pos, end_pos)
    if pos_pair in cache:
        return cache[pos_pair]
    if start_pos > end_pos:
        dq = deque()
        dq.append(None)
        cache[pos_pair] = dq
        return cache[pos_pair]
    if start_pos == end_pos:
        if trie.search(input_phrase[start_pos]) == 1:
            dq = deque()
            dq.append((start_pos, start_pos))
            cache[pos_pair] = dq
            return cache[pos_pair]
        cache[pos_pair] = None
        return cache[pos_pair]
    for break_pos in range(start_pos, end_pos + 1):
        phrase_substring = input_phrase[start_pos : break_pos + 1]
        search_result = trie.search(phrase_substring)
        if search_result == 0:
            break
        if search_result == 2:
            continue
        sub_ans_dq = partition_valid_words(break_pos + 1, end_pos, trie, input_phrase, cache)
        if sub_ans_dq is None:
            continue
        sub_ans_dq.appendleft((start_pos, break_pos))
        cache[pos_pair] = sub_ans_dq
        return cache[pos_pair]
    cache[pos_pair] = None
    return cache[pos_pair]


def add_spaces(dq, input_phrase):
    if dq is None:
        return None
    sentence = []
    for elem in dq:
        if elem is None or len(elem) < 2:
            continue
        word = input_phrase[elem[0]: elem[1]+1]
        sentence.append(word)
    return sentence


def main():
    input_phrase = "categoricaldataandprobabilities"
    words_dict = ['categorical', 'data', 'and', 'probabilities']
    trie = Trie()
    for word in words_dict:
        trie.insert(word)
    ans = partition_valid_words(0, len(input_phrase) - 1, trie, input_phrase, {})
    ans = ' '.join(add_spaces(ans, input_phrase))
    print(ans)


main()
```

You will need to mind the capitalization.
In your dataset, the first letter is capitalized.
Since we do a case-sensitive matching in the recursive algorithm, we must first make all the dataset lower-case completely.
You can transform the resulting dataset's first letter to caps back again.